Error with org-refile and RFLOC in a custom function
I am using Doom Emacs and org-roam, while very useful, org-refile is hard to use in this configuration mostly because of readability issues.
I have a custom consult-org-read function that lets me pick a refile target, and returns a marker. I am trying to use this marker in a org-refile wrapper, but it is harder than I thought.
After many attempts I think I got the code right to turn the marker into a valid RFLOC argument expected by org-refile. The problem is I keep getting a "Cannot refile to region or subtree" error.
I located the error call in org-refile source code, but I do not understand it. I found this related answer, and I feel like I am doing the same. I tested picking the same item to refile, and the same location with a direct call to org-refile, it works fine.
I have no idea where to go from there. Maybe I need to understand better how exactly the refile location target should be specified, that would help me understand what is wrong with my code. My marker might not be good enough to begin with.
(defun org-refile--to-marker (marker)
 
  (when (and (markerp marker) (marker-buffer marker))
    (let ((buffer (marker-buffer marker)))
      (with-current-buffer buffer
        (goto-char marker)

        (let ((name (org-get-heading t t t t))
              (file (expand-file-name (buffer-file-name)))
              (pos (marker-position marker)))

          (org-refile nil nil (list name file nil pos)))))))

=== EDIT ===
I tried to find out more about the exact location that should be passed as RFLOC. To do so, I tested the following snippet from the answer previously linked:
(pos (save-excursion
               (find-file file)
               (org-find-exact-headline-in-buffer headline))

According to the post, the marker returned by this code should work. Testing (always with the same items to refile, and target), the marker I am using is exactly the same as the one this snippet returns. So I think this eliminates a potential flaw in the way I obtain my refile target location. The error should be in my org-refile--to-marker function I guess.
=== EDIT ===
After more tests, I really cannot see what more I can do. RFLOC seems fine, I tried different combinations of arguments out of frustration.
The only thing I have left to do is understand the following code throwing the error. I tried a few times, but I need to spend much more time on it.
      (when (and (not arg)
             pos
             (equal (buffer-file-name) file)
             (if regionp
             (and (>= pos region-start)
                  (<= pos region-end))
               (and (>= pos (save-excursion
                                     (org-back-to-heading t)
                                     (point)))
                (< pos (save-excursion
                     (org-end-of-subtree t t))))))
        (error "Cannot refile to position inside the tree or region"))

Any pointer would be appreciated. Thanks.

You may find this code helpful https://github.com/akirak/org-reverse-datetree/blob/d029e2263de23b19ed89f9757ad69b7cb33bda32/org-reverse-datetree.el#L374-L378

Thank you, the (nth 4 (org-heading-components)) bit was helpful to confirm the last part of my RFLOC I was unsure of. It seems that my code is fine for that part. I need to investigate further and try to understand the code I posted in my edit.

I haven't looked at the code in context, but the above says that if all of the following are true, then raise the error: 1) arg is nil; 2) pos is non-nil; 3) the file argument is the same as the filename associated with the current buffer; 4) regionp is true and pos is inside the region OR regionp is false and pos is inside the current subtree. 3), 4) and 5) basically check whether you are refiling to the same place that you are refiling from. I would instrument org-refile (or whatever function contains the above code) for edebug and step through it.

Yes, the refile of org-reverse-datetree works and you can refer the org-reverse-datetree--refile-to-file and org-reverse-datetree-2 functions to debug.

I should have read your function org-refile--to-marker more carefully: you are doing the org-refile from the buffer that you are refiling to. You have to do it from the buffer you are refiling from. Skip the (with-current-buffer buffer ... IOW. The error you got is a direct result of this.

That's wrong: do all the calculation within the with-current-buffer but do NOT do the org-refile in that context. See my answer.

In your function, you are making the destination buffer current, IOW you are trying to refile from the destination buffer to the same buffer - hence the error. You should not put the org-refile inside (with-current-buffer buffer ...). You can calculate everything except the name without making the destination buffer current, but for name you will need to do that. Here's one way to do it:
(defun org-refile--to-marker (marker)
  (when (and (markerp marker) (marker-buffer marker))
    (let ((buffer (marker-buffer marker))
          name file pos)
      (setq name (with-current-buffer buffer
                   (goto-char marker)
                   (org-get-heading t t t t)))
      (setq file (expand-file-name (buffer-file-name buffer)))
      (setq pos (marker-position marker))

      (org-refile nil nil (list name file nil pos)))))


Untested.

Thank you for catching that mistake, your solution works. I still have to understand better how to pass an RFLOC that is in fact located in the same buffer, but another tree since org-refile is capable of doing it, but my function throws an error, but all other scenarios work fine now thanks to your fix.

If pos is not in the selected region or it is not in the same subtree as point, then you should be able to refile there with no problems. The modified function in my answer should be able to do that. If you get an error with that, ask another question with the new details.

Thanks for the pointers. After a little debugging, I found that englobing the (goto-char marker) and the (org-get-heading t t t t) in a (save-excursion) call solves the issue when refiling to the same buffer using your code above.
